# Detect Tap in UITextView Objective C uneditable and unselectable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a button and a UITextView, the button has an IBAction that prints Hello World, I want it that when I tap the UITextView, it will also do the same function as the button. I currently have this code in my viewDidLoad..

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(helloWorldPressed:)];
gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
[_messageTextLine1 addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```

Here is my function

```
- (IBAction)helloWorldPressed:(id)sender {
        NSLog(@"Hello World!");
}
```

Note that I already have a

`<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>`

in my .h file.

Additional Note : The UITextView is **NOT** editable and **NOT** selectable

How can I do it that when I tap the TextView it will act like the button, and do the same function helloWorldPressed?

Should I create a new function for the gesture to do that basically does the same thing? What do you think can I do? Thanks!

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @NiravD how can I do it that when I tap the TextView it will act like the button, and do the same function helloWorldPressed

Comment: If you are adding the same `gestureRecognizer` instance for both `button` and `textView` then it will not works you need to create two different instance for both UI elements.

Comment: There is no gestureRecognizer for the button it is linked as a IBAction, i tried creating a new function that does the same, changed the selector of the gestureRecognizer but still didn't work.

Comment: Because of your UITextView  NOT editable and NOT selectable, that means you set  `_messageTextLine1 .userInteractionEnabled = NO`, so it can't observe any gesture.

Comment: Got the answer! i just added _messageTextLine1 .userInteractionEnabled = YES and it worked. You can put that as an answer and I'll mark it right. Thanks @nynohu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of your `UITextView` NOT editable and NOT selectable, that means you set `_messageTextLine1 .userInteractionEnabled = NO`, so it can't observe any gesture. Change to `_messageTextLine1 .userInteractionEnabled = YES` and it will work.